# pthread_attr_setschedparam() returns non zero but errno = success ... (Linux, C, Ubuntu 18.04.4)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, pthreads

Good day all stack overflow peeps !

Have this code in my program which exits on error ... but with Success?
Not sure why?

Output:

- dateTime - RLIMIT_RTTIME: soft=-1, hard=-1
- dateTime - RLIMIT_RTPRIO: soft=-1, hard=-1
- dateTime - RLIMIT_CPU: soft=-1, hard=-1
- dateTime - main() - pthread_attr_setschedParam()
- Success

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>



char      strNowTime[26];



//-----------------------------------
// signal Handler stuff.
//-----------------------------------
static
struct  sigaction mySigActTerm;

volatile
int     myTerminate = 0;

void terminateHandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
  // set a flag here and get out.
  myTerminate = 1;
}



void getNowTime(char* str)
{
  time_t    rawtime;
  time(&rawtime);
  ctime_r(&rawtime, str);

  // clobber the unwanted newline.
  str[24] = '\0';
}



void myResLimit()
{
  struct
  rlimit    procLimit;

  getrlimit(RLIMIT_RTTIME, &procLimit);
  getNowTime(strNowTime);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s - RLIMIT_RTTIME: soft=%lld, hard=%lld\n", strNowTime, (long long) procLimit.rlim_cur, (long long)procLimit.rlim_max);

  getrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, &procLimit);
  getNowTime(strNowTime);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s - RLIMIT_RTPRIO: soft=%lld, hard=%lld\n", strNowTime, (long long) procLimit.rlim_cur, (long long) procLimit.rlim_max);

  getrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &procLimit);
  getNowTime(strNowTime);
  fprintf(stderr, "%s - RLIMIT_CPU: soft=%lld, hard=%lld\n", strNowTime, (long long) procLimit.rlim_cur, (long long) procLimit.rlim_max);
}



void*   serialThread(void* arg)
{
    while (1) {
        
    }
}



//-----------------------------------
// the one and only MAIN.
//-----------------------------------
int main()
{
  //-----------------------------------------------
  // locals.
  int               rtn;
  int               myErr;

  pthread_t         serialThdID;

  pthread_attr_t*   serialAttr;

  struct
  sched_param       serialParam;


  //-----------------------------------------------
  // Log OS resource limits.
  myResLimit();

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // initialize the signals struct.
  // ... and setup signals.
  memset(&mySigActTerm, 0, sizeof(mySigActTerm));
  mySigActTerm.sa_sigaction = terminateHandler;
  mySigActTerm.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

  sigaction(SIGTERM, &mySigActTerm, NULL);


  //-----------------------------------------------
  // setup the pthread attributes struct.
  if ((serialAttr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t))) == NULL) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_t malloc()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  memset(serialAttr, 0, sizeof(pthread_attr_t));

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // set initial default pthread attr values.
  if (pthread_attr_init(serialAttr) != 0) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_init()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // set for best near real time policy.
  if (pthread_attr_setschedpolicy(serialAttr, SCHED_FIFO) !=0) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_setschedpolicy()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // set to explicit inherit or attr obj will be ignored.
  if (pthread_attr_setinheritsched(serialAttr, PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED) !=0) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_setinheritsched()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // set to un-limited thread priority.
  serialParam.sched_priority = 0;
  if (pthread_attr_setschedparam(serialAttr, &serialParam) !=0) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_setschedparam()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // start the new thread.
  rtn = pthread_create(&serialThdID, serialAttr, serialThread, NULL);
  myErr = errno;
  if(rtn  == 0) {
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - starting serial thread.\n", strNowTime);
  }
  else {
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_create() returned %d\n%s\n", strNowTime, rtn, strerror(myErr));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  //-----------------------------------------------
  // no need to keep this junk if pthread_create() succeeded.
  if (pthread_attr_destroy(serialAttr) != 0) {
    myErr = errno;
    getNowTime(strNowTime);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s - main() - pthread_attr_destroy()\n%s\n", strNowTime, strerror(myErr));
  }
  // research proves this is needed if we malloc'ed!
  free(serialAttr);



  while (myTerminate == 0) {

  }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there is no reason to use `malloc` to get the attribute object. Just declare an object of type `pthread_attr_t` rather than a pointer to one, and use its address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_attr_setschedpolicy` does not set `errno`. From the [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setschedpolicy.3.html):

> RETURN VALUE
>
> On success, these functions return 0; on error, they return a nonzero error number.

That is, the error number is in the return value itself and not in `errno`.

In fact, none of the pthread functions set `errno`. See the [pthread_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) manual for an example of how it calls `perror` when a pthread function fails. It actually manually sets `errno` first:

```
#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
           do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
```

Comment: I have corrected the code and now I get Invalid Argument.

Comment: Not sure why though ... I assume I should start another question since this has been answered?

Comment: @keithbradley Yes please post a new question if you still can't work it out. The [sched](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html) man page may help you: *Processes scheduled under one of the real-time policies
       (SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR) have a sched_priority value in the range 1
       (low) to 99 (high).*

Answer (score 0):

As clearly documented, `pthread_attr_setschedparam` **returns the error code** on failure. It does not set `errno`. (Technically it's allowed, like most other functions are allowed, to clobber errno with any nonzero value, but this is not "setting" it in the sense of providing a meaningful value.) You need to save the return value and use that, not `errno`, as the error code to report.

Comment: Thank you R ... also great answer ... but I assume I am supposed to give credit to who is first?

Comment: @keithbradley, you are at your own discretion to choose which answer, if any, to accept.  You can even change your mind.  You may use the timing of the answers as one of your criteria, but you are not obligated to do so.